# Op Amp Output Distorted

Tags: operational-amplifier

I have OPA355 configured as inverting unity gain. My input signal source is a 10MHz sine wave, with vpeak as 1 V. This opamp is a CMOS based and has very low Ibias current (~pA). With a Gain of 1, the 3dB bandwidth is 450MHz. I expect this to work for a signal of 10MHz. Here is the schematic
[image: Schematic]

Apparently the output is getting clipped (expect the output to swing between 3.5 and 1.5 Volts). Here is the output and input waveform
[image: Waveforms]

Could anyone suggest, what's the issue here and how I can fix this?

Comment: Widen your voltage rails. The op amp can't output a voltage that isn't between its V+ and V-.

Comment: My input signal is between, 3.5 and 1.5. THe opamp is configured as inverting unity gain amplifier, so the output has enough headroom.

Comment: Well, have you looked at whether it works in steady-state? Clipping during transients is one thing, clipping in steady-state is another.

Comment: Did you allow enough time for C1 & C2 to charge up?

Comment: Hi Tony, I will run the sim for longer time and see if it improves.

Comment: Hi Tony, I reran the simulation for longer time. It doesn't help.

Comment: What happens if you reduce R1, R2, R3 to 3K?

Comment: If you see the output amplitude wax/wane it's also oscillating at some fo

Comment: Your input signal is between +/-10V according to your own graphs.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany yes, the output is proper with R1, R2, R3 as 3K. Unfortunately R1 is the source impedance of signal source. I can't reduce it.

Comment: Very hard to believe in a 10MHz signal source with a 300k source impedance. Are you sure it isn't 300 *ohms*?

Comment: I am modelling a Photo Multiplier Tube, pretty sure the source impedance is 300k.

Comment: That is going to be challenging .. Probably not impossible but challenging. Perhaps you could say a bit more about the application?

Comment: Hi Spehro, this PMT will generate pulses (different types). I want to buffer the pulses before doing any analog signal processing on them like peak detection, integration.  The pulses are negative (-18 DC level, min -23 V), that's why I have an AC coupling cap, I want my output to be inverted and set around a positive DC level.

Comment: I think you will need to reduce the PMT load resistance and add amplification (with adequate bandwidth). Even 1pF of stray capacitance will reduce your BW to 0.5MHz with 300k source resistance. There are ways to reduce the effective capacitance to less than 1pF but they are troublesome in most cases.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Could I terminate the signal source with a 50 ohm resistance? this would reduce the source resistance to 50 ohm. I would lose a lot of signal (due to voltage division), then I can buffer and amplify the signal with lower feedback resistors.

Comment: Sure. The voltage will be proportionally less. Note that you will need a *much* better amplifier or several stages of amplification- the OPA355 has a GBW of only 200MHz.  300K/50 ohms is  6000:1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 300kOhm feedback resistor, combined with the input capacitance of __ pF mentioned in the datasheet (page 3) creates a pole at __ Hz...

I'm not copypasting the values, that's your job, but I'll give you a hint: there is no way this is going to work at 10MHz (unless the opamp model does not include input capacitance, of course).

Comment: Hi Peufeu, Thanks. Having 300K has introduced a pole at 3.5 MHz. I just verified using AC response.

Comment: Doesn't mean you can't make it work add a compensation capacitor across R1 of the same magnitude

Comment: Compensation will reduce the BW substantially, I need to make it work for 10MHz signals.

Comment: Yeah you'll need a lower resistor value, make sure you don't go too low (check the available output current and recommended resistor values in datasheet)

Answer (score 1):

This is often a slew rate issue.  While the bandwidth may be fine, and small signals will be hunky dory, big signals get messed up.

In this case, this is not the issue, as your peak slope for your signal is \$12.6 \frac{V}{\mu s}\$, and the max slew rate for your op amp is  \$300 \frac{V}{\mu s}\$, but it's still worth pointing out.

Comment: lots of slew rate and GBW avail. It's a transient input bias issue